# Prepend list in javascript in different methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am adding new element to a object list, each object contains a variable `value` and a  variable `rest`, which has its value as next object. the relevant code to convert array to list is:

```
function arrayToList (array) {
    var obj = {
        value: array[array.length-1],
        rest: null
    }
    var temp = obj;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length-1; ++i) {
        var obj = {
            value: array[array.length-2-i],
            rest: temp
        }
        temp = obj;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

**My problem** is with following code, prepend function, I need to add element to start of list. I did it in two ways, one the commented way which failed and other the object creation way which works fine. I don;t know whats wrong with **commented failed method**.

```
function prepend(objList, val) {
    // Failed method
    /*var newObj = objList;
    newObj.value = val;
    newObj.rest = objList;
    */        

    var newObj = {
        value: val,
        rest: objList
    };
    return newObj;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: blind guess.  `newObj.value = value;` should be `newObj.value = val;`

Comment: @mishel thank you I made error while typing here. it still doesn't work, it makes all elements of list same value as `val`

Comment: Why do you create a variable named `obj`, then save it into `temp` immediately? And then create another variable `obj` in your `for - loop`? Do you know that doing `var temp = obj;` only copies the reference to the `obj` variable into `temp`, it doesn't actually create a new `Object` in the `temp` variable?

Comment: @blundering no i didnt know that, what can i doto overcome this

Comment: @blundering oh so if I change that variable which is reference, it actually changes the variable who it refers, so that also created problem in prepend function

Comment: @jeea exactly, which is what Matus is explaining below. If you want to copy an `Object` (or `Array`, which is technically an `Object` in js), I'd recommend doing something like `var temp = Object.assign({}, obj);` or `var temp = { ...obj };` using the spread operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change that failing code to this and it will work. You probably want a new object to start with not a **live** reference to the old one.

```
var newObj = {};
newObj.value = val;
newObj.rest = objList;
```

```js
function arrayToList (array) {
    var obj = {
        value: array[array.length-1],
        rest: null
    }
    var temp = obj;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length-1; ++i) {
        var obj = {
            value: array[array.length-2-i],
            rest: temp
        }
        temp = obj;
    }

    return temp;
}

function prepend(objList, val) {
    // updated 
    var newObj = {};
    newObj.value = val;
    newObj.rest = objList;
    
    // var newObj = {
    //     value: val,
    //     rest: objList
    // };
    return newObj;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(prepend(arrayToList(arr), 10));
```

Or you can copy `objList` in the `prepend` method using `Object.assign`

```
var newObj = Object.assign({}, objList);
newObj.value = val;
newObj.rest = objList;
```

Comment: I does work thanks a lot, but why `newObj = objList` causes strange error?

Comment: Your answer code is actually what I need, but now I am curious what the  failing code `var newObj = objList;` isdoing

Comment: @jeea  That is because object assignment doesn't create a copy of an object but simply reference to the same object therefore your `newObj` and `newObj.rest` is live reference to the same object, if you change one, you change the other. That causes that strange behavior. You can try creating a copy of that object by using `Object.assign({}, objList)` and that will work because it produces a copy (shallow one) of an object instead of just passing a reference.

Comment: Pretty complicated, i thought javascript was easy